# SharePoint Online Access Request Update Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, requestaccessmail

In sharepoint online I have created 20 sites for a client, they created an account for me and I used that account to create sites.

Now sometime I get emails for request access, where should I update the email address to their Internal IT consultant so he get emails and approve or reject access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Access request Settings (Ribbon) -> *"Send all requests for access to the following e-mail address:
"*
[image]

More info - [Set up and manage access requests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3)

Comment: do I need to update all sites with the new email address?

Comment: Usually access request settings configured under root site level, so you don't need to update all subsites individually. Only in case if your sub-site has unique permissions, you need to go to the sub site's settings and change access request.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest csom dll or a version `16.1.4727.1200` or above.

You can use the below code in a loop to change the settings:

```
// web is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web object

web.Context.Load(web, w => w.MembersCanShare);   
web.Context.ExecuteQuery(); 
web.MembersCanShare = true; 
web.Update(); 
web.Context.Load(web, w => w.MembersCanShare); 
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();

web.Context.Load(web, w => w.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership); 
web.Context.ExecuteQuery(); 
web.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = true`; 
web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Update(); 
web.Context.Load(web, w => w.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership); 
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.RequestAccessEmail); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
clientContext.Web.RequestAccessEmail = clientContext.Site.Owner.Email; //change the email address here
//clientContext.Web.RequestAccessEmail = "user@tenant.com"
clientContext.Web.Update(); 
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.RequestAccessEmail); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[CSOM change access request settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandru/2015/12/31/sharepoint-onlinecsom-change-access-requests-settings/)